# How to have the overflow of a scrollable element still visible beyond the bounds of a fixed width container?

Tags: html, css

I need a container with a fixed width, and an element inside it that can scroll within that fixed width. The catch is that I need the content that goes beyond the bounds of the fixed width container to be visible. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Codepen of the situation I'm describing: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zyZOjM

```css
.outer {
  background: red;
  width: 400px;
  height: 800px;
}

.inner {
  background: blue;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  height: 300px;
  color: white;
}

.element {
  background: green;
  width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="element">Initially, this element should overflow all the way off the edge of the red (exactly how it does when overflow is set to visible). It should be scrollable, though (how it is when overflow is set to scroll) and when you scroll all the way to the right,
      the right of the green should end at the same place is does now (right edge of the blue).</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm pretty stumped. This could have a simple solution but I've been pulling my hair out a bit.

Comment: How to have the *overflow* of a *scrollable* element still *visible* ---> two contradictory things in the same sentence. Either scrollable or visible

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yet that is the desired behavior. I need it to be visible beyond the bounds but scroll-able within them. I know this is difficult to achieve, that's why I'm posting it here (I have no idea how to pull it off)

Comment: it's not about *difficult* but it seems counter intuitive and not logical .. Why you want the scroll if you want the overflow to be visible? to scroll what if the overflow is visible?

Comment: @TemaniAfif this is a simplified version of something I am attempting to build for a product and this behavior is the expectation/design. I believe the idea is that the content going all the way to the right off the page makes it clear to the user that there is content there they cannot see, whereas if it gets cut off by the fixed width container which has the same background color as the page, it can be harder to spot that there is content there they're missing at their browser's width

Comment: so better give more context to your question to get better answers. A simplified version will hide a lot of details that we need to tackle the issue. If you describe your use case you will probably getter better ideas than what you are trying to do

Comment: by the way you can make the element `position: absolute;` without adjusting anything else and you will have what you want

Answer (score 0):

Is this what want to achieve?

```
.container1 {
  background: red;
  width:400px;
  height:800px;

}

.doop1 {
  background:blue;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin:auto;
  overflow: auto;
  height:300px;
  overflow-Y: hiddden;
}

.doop2 {
  background:green;
  width:800px;
  height:100px;
}

#overflow-text{
  display: block;
  width: 190px;
  position:fixed;
}


<div class="container1">
  <div class="doop1">
    <div class="doop2">
      <p id="overflow-text">
      Initially, this element should overflow all the way to the edge of the red. When you scroll all the way to the right, the green should end at the same place is does now (edge of the blue).
        </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```